# How to I create a control for music?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I want to create controls for the MediaPlayer Class in android which will play a music with seekbar, a play/pause button, a fast button and a slow button.

How can I achieve this can anyone help me with it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very good tutorial...
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-music-player-on-android-project-setup--mobile-22764

A search an Google and I find this:
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-UniversalMusicPlayer
That's for download and is very good.

Comment: I have seen this and its greate

Comment: @ASK: Where's your snapshot?